# Масштабируемость приложений Windows Forms

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Как можно обеспечить пропорциональное масштабирование оконных приложений, написанных VS C#? Чтобы элементы окна, при его развертывании оставались на расстоянии, пропорциональном измененному размеру формы.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Используйте контролы из категории контейнеры; cкорей всего, вам понадобится [TableLayoutPanel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.tablelayoutpanel.aspx). С его помощью нужно будет разметить основной каркас формы, а размеры всех строк и столбцов задать в процентах. Далее, добавляем нужный контрол в ячейку таблицы и, если вы хотите масштабирования за счёт расстояния между контролами — устанавливаем свойство `Anchor` равным `None`. Если нужна масштабируемость по размеру — `Dock` равным `Full`.

И, конечно, одной табличкой вы не ограничитесь. Скорей всего придётся использовать вложенные.

Answer (score 1):

Вряд ли есть простой способ. Можно сделать так:

1. создать массив координат контролов (например, по левому верхнему краю) на форме,
2. переопределить обработчик `WM_SIZING` для формы,
3. в обработчике пересчитать массив координат с помощью Graphics.TransformPoints и передвинуть контролы.